# Deleting from vector and QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I use QT and have a vector and a QVBoxLayout filled with Widgets. It's no Problem to fill both with an `Add` Button, but deleting them doesn't really work.

If I delete the Widgets from last to first everything works just fine, but when I try to delete them in any other way everything fails. Maybe someone has an idea?

```
void listwindow::remove_entry()
{
 vector<todo_list_entry *>::iterator pos;

 int i=0;
 for (pos=list_entrys_vector.begin();pos<=list_entrys_vector.end();pos++)
 {
  if((**pos).check_delete()==true)
  {
   listenLayout->removeWidget(*pos);
   listenLayout->update();
   list_entrys_vector.erase(pos);
   delete list_entrys_vector[i];
   break;
  }
  i++;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having a problem with iterator invalidation from using `erase` on elements of a vector while iterating over it. Once you do `list_entrys_vector.erase(pos)`, `pos` is no longer a valid iterator, so when you try to use it the next time through the loop, bad things happen. Instead of using erase on each individual element of the vector while you are iterating through, wait until the end and erase them all at once using `list_entrys_vector.clear()`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to delete all of the entries, do that with a combination of `remove_if` and then `erase`. If `f` is a function that takes an entry and returns `true` if it should be removed, you can do this.

```
pos = std::remove_if(list_entrys_vector.begin(),list_entrys_vector.end(),f);
```

Now, the entries that you want to remove are at the end of the vector and pos points to the first one that should be removed. You can then do the other stuff to these entries, then do

```
list_entrys_vector.erase(pos,list_entrys_vector.end());
```

There are other ways to accomplish this, but the key to remember is that you can't erase elements from a vector while you are iterating through it. If you want to do that you have to use something like `std::list`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to this and now it seems like the vector erease works just fine, but listenLayout gives me some trouble... if i add 4 elements and delete the first, i can only see 3 and 4 and after removing the 4 the 2 suddenly appears...

```
void listwindow::remove_entry()
{
 vector<todo_list_entry *> buffer_vector;
 vector<todo_list_entry *>::iterator pos;


 for ( pos = list_entrys_vector.begin(); pos != list_entrys_vector.end(); ) {
    if((**pos).check_delete()==true) {
       delete * pos;
       pos = list_entrys_vector.erase(pos);
       listenLayout->removeWidget(*pos);
       listenLayout->update;
    }
    else {
       ++pos;
    }
 }
```

edit:
changed the order (first removeWidget, then delete) now everything works great!